# how to calculate motor power for electric truck

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a 50,500 kgs semi-trailer to modify to be electric truck.
I will mount a motor direct to differntial axis ( without gearbox ).
Differential ratio is 841 ( 5.125 ).
If I want this 50,500 kgs semi-trailer to climb a 26 % slope , what is the suitable motor power for this truck.

Comment: Still wheels diameter and expect speed missing . But I can ballpark you will definitely need a gearbox in between

Comment: Your diff ratio is that 8.4 : 1 or 84 : 1 or 841 : 1 ? Confused...  IIRC C&U regs require 4.4kW per 1000kg as a minimum...

Comment: Homework?  Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: Differential ratio = 5.125 .       Tyre diameter = 1.04 m.      Expect speed while climbing the 26% slope = 12 km/hour.